# How do i get my footer to cover the whole width of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i came across some kind of bugg where my footer doesn't cover the complete width of the site anymore like its supposed to be in (image 2) how do i fix this?

[How it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9fkt.jpg)

[How it's supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J03N2.jpg)

Comment: Do not share the website. Instead share code that reproduces your problem. My first thought is that you used bootstrap or maybe even VisualComposer or Elementor to make your site and the footer is not stretched but instead boxed to be as wide as the `container`. The footer should be in a `container-fluid` class.

Answer (score 1):

The footer is in div with class=container and id=hero and this is limiting it. Move the footer out of the div :D